# Download extension pack to import in my app

Tags: android

I have did an application with a lot of images and now the size of the project is 28MB. So I think that the user can download this images from my WebServer and then import it in the application. How i can do this ?

P.S. I don't wont that the images can be clearly visible in the SD card

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Expansion file mechanism](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html). It has been designed by the Android team to solve exactly that problem. You can split your application into at most 50 MB app + 2 GB data in a first file + 2 GB data in a second file.

Everything is managed by the Google market, so that should be a more stable solution than using the own webserver.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but i would that the user can choose the images to download. For example if the user want to play level 1, he'll download the packet with 10MB of images... The same thing for level 2, 3, 4... With this method if he don't want to play level 2 (for example) he don't have 10MB of images in his SDCard

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that does not exist in practice. There are Android users who will not download large data at all, because they have limited devices or limited data plans. And then there are people who download large apps, independent of whether it is 50 or 500 MB. By splitting your app in so many parts, you are annyoing your users more than helping them, probably.